# Как сделать спрайтовую анимацию?

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Как сделать спрайтовую анимацию,чтобы можно было разобраться и удобно настроить (ширину картинки и количество слайдов)? И еще нужно сделать чтобы персонаж двигался вперед.
Есть такой код:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/jfhp8o21/
```

```js
var styles = {};
styles.width = '112px';
styles.height = '150px';

spriteAnimation('mk', 'https://inter-net.pro/images/css/sprite-marsch.png', styles);

function spriteAnimation(elementId, imgName, styles) {

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  var offset = 0;
  img.onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.width = styles.width;
    element.style.height = styles.height;
    element.style.background = "url('" + imgName + "') " + offset + "px 50%";
    var i = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (offset < img.width) {
        i = i + 18;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      offset = 8.8 * i;
      element.style.background = "url('" + imgName + "') " + offset + "px 50%";

    }, 1000 / 6)
  }
  img.src = imgName;
}
```

```html
<div id="mk"></div>
```

,но он очень странно работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он очень странно работает, потому что вы используете очень странные цифры.
Вот этот кусок, это [какая то древняя магия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), и она не работает:

```
if (offset < img.width) {
    i = i + 18; // что за 18?
} else {
    i = 0;
}
offset = 8.8 * i; // Что за 8.8?
```

i пусть лучше будет счетчиком кадров.
А коэффицент умножения получается делением ширины картинки на количество спрайтов. И тогда всё более менее ровненько:

```js
var styles = {
  width: 112,
  height: 150
};

var frames = 6; // Количество кадров
var speed = 8; // Размер одного шага

spriteAnimation('mk', 'https://inter-net.pro/images/css/sprite-marsch.png', styles);

function spriteAnimation(elementId, imgName, styles) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  var offset = 0;
  img.onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.width = styles.width+'px';
    element.style.height = styles.height+'px';
    element.style.background = "url('" + imgName + "') " + offset + "px 50%";
    // i - номер кадра, pos - позиция персонажа (от левого края)
    var i = 0, pos = 0;
    // размер одного спрайта в пикселях
    var step = img.width / frames;
    
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      // i крутиться от 5 до 0
      // пришлось пустить счетчик задом наперёд, иначе он как будто шагает назад
      if (--i < 0) i = frames - 1; 
      offset = step * i; // offset теперь проще вычислить.
      element.style.background = "url('" + imgName + "') " + offset + "px 50%";
      // И еще нужно сделать чтобы персонаж двигался вперед.
      pos += speed;
      element.style.marginLeft = pos + 'px';
    }, 1000 / 6)
  }
  img.src = imgName;
}
```

```html
<div id="mk"></div>
```

Comment: жесть мне очень понравился этот пример